# If $f_n(t) \to f(t)$ as $n \to \infty$ and $f_n(t) \to 0$ as $t \to 0$ then does $f_n(t_n) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $f_n:[0,T] \to X$ be a sequence of maps into a Hilbert space $X$.

We know $f_n(t) \to f(t)$ as $n \to \infty$ for each $t$, and also $f_n(t) \to 0$ as $t \to 0$ (I don't know whether this is uniform with respect to $n$).

We also know that $t \mapsto f_n(t)$ is continuous on $(0,1)$.

Are there any other conditions on the $f_n$ that would tell me that $f_n(t_n) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ if $t_n$ is a sequence such that $t_n \to 0$?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Uniform convergence in $n$ is hard to check so was hoping for other conditions

Comment: Sorry, bad counterexample, so a new comment: $f_n(t)=nt\cdot(1-t)^n$, $t_n=\frac1{n}$. Then $f_n(t_n)\to e^{-1}$. - I'm afraid you wpn't get along with anything much weaker than uniform convergence

Comment: Indeed, if you were to slightly strengthen your desired conclusion to "$f_n(t_n)\to f(t)$ whenever $t_n\to t$", then this is equivalent to uniform convergence.